# Angular code not working with express

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, express

Am having a problem with angular. My angular code works fine when i run it alone but doesn't work when i access it on localhost with express. What happens is that it displays the html file alone.
 my server code is : 
*

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/client/main.html');
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('I\'m listening...');
})
```

my angular controller code is

```
var app = angular.module('tiks', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){

     $scope.posts = [];
     $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', create_at: ''};

      $scope.post = function(){
        $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
        $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
        $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };
});
```

and the angularised html code is

```
<!--main.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tiks</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/tiks.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="tiks">
    <div id='main' ng-controller="mainController">
     <form ng-Submit="post()">
        <input required type="text" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by" /> 
        <textarea required maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
      </form>
      <div id="post-stream">
        <h4>Tiks Feed</h4>
              <div class='post' ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
            <p>{{post.created_by}} says {{post.text}} at {{post.created_at}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help

Comment: You are not telling express to serve your static content https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is asking for `javascripts/tiks.js` at the `script` tag, but your server has no route configured to serve it.

Try checking the requests being done, for example using [Google Chrome Developer tools network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading), and you will probably see a `404` error when the `.js` file is requested.

You should use [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve files from folder instead of defining specific resources individually as you are doing for `./app/client/main.html`.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/app/client/'));
```

then you would have to access `http://localhost/main.html` to access it.

Comment: You should suggest how to fix it, that is use middleware to handle static files https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: 10x for your reply how do i add the route ?

Comment: hmmm, ok, I edited with the `/` param to make it more clear

Comment: i added app.use(express.static('./app/client/javascripts')); to my code on the server but no luck

Comment: Did you do with the `/` param as it is now? (I edited the answer)